# Import features QGIS WFS

Tags: qgis, wfs, getfeature

I am trying to import features via the WFS. I can connect and it shows me the layer names. However, depending on what layer I choose it just adds a table, sometimes with giberish as content, sometimes no content at all. I tried using the WFS 1.0 "add layer" approach as well as using the WFS 2.0 plugin.

The WFS url is:
https://www.geodatenportal.sachsen-anhalt.de/wss/service/ST_LVermGeo_ATKIS_WFS_BDLM_OpenData/guest?

This is the site (in german) where i got the URL from:
https://geodatenportal.sachsen-anhalt.de/gfds/de/gdp-open-data.html

In the end I want to access the "AX_Gebauede" layer.

[image]

This is the attribute table of "AX_Gebaude"

[image]
The WFS windows after I clicked "connect"

Comment: assume you mean `AX_Gebaeude`

Comment: Service provides complex features so you will need the GMLAS plugin I think to get anything to work in QGIS; however specifically for  `adv:AX_Gebaeude`  a GetFeature request returns no results ~ https://www.geodatenportal.sachsen-anhalt.de/wss/service/ST_LVermGeo_ATKIS_WFS_BDLM_OpenData/guest?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&typenames=adv:AX_Gebaeude&resultType=hits